Django admin panel shows field max length instead of field name
I know it is a little bit weird but I see field max length instead of field name in admin panel as below:

My model:
class SituationFlag(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(30)
slug=models.SlugField(null=False,blank=True, unique=True,editable=False,max_length=30)
description =models.CharField(200)
cssclass=models.CharField(30)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.name
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.slug=slugify(self.name)
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)

Also I'm using that SituationFlag model with many-many relationship in other model as below:
class Subject(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()
is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
slug=models.SlugField(null=False,blank=True, unique=True,db_index=True,editable=False,max_length=255)
category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete= models.SET_NULL,null=True)
situation_flag=models.ManyToManyField(SituationFlag)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.title

def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.slug=slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)

What am I missing here?
Any help would be much appreciated.

You did not pass these to the max_length=… [Django-doc], but to the verbose_name=… [Django-doc]. Use a named parameter:
class SituationFlag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        null=False, blank=True, unique=True, editable=False, max_length=30
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cssclass = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


Note: Specifying null=False [Django-doc] is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.



Note: You can make use of django-autoslug [GitHub] to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).

